# Vector Layer is not showing in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, geodjango, openlayers-3

I am using GeoDjango and my basemap is BingMaps. When I view the source code GeoJSON data was there but it doesn't show up as layer. In my admin using OSMGeoAdmin, it does show.
[image]

Here's the snippet of my JS:

```
 var styles = [
     'Road',
     'Aerial',
     'AerialWithLabels'];
 var layers = [];
 var i, ii;
 for (i = 0, ii = styles.length; i < ii; ++i) {
     layers.push(new ol.layer.Tile({
         visible: false,
         preload: Infinity,
         source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
             key: 'Ak-dzM4wZjSqTlzveKz5u0d4IQ4bRzVI309GxmkgSVr1ewS6iPSrOvOKhA-CJlm3',
             imagerySet: styles[i]
             // use maxZoom 19 to see stretched tiles instead of the BingMaps
             // "no photos at this zoom level" tiles
             // maxZoom: 19
         })
     }));
 }

 var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
     source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
         {
             flood_hazard | safe
         }
     })
 });
 var map = new ol.Map({
     layers: [layers, vectorLayer],
     renderer: exampleNS.getRendererFromQueryString(),
     // Improve user experience by loading tiles while dragging/zooming. Will make
     // zooming choppy on mobile or slow devices.
     loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
     target: 'map',
     view: new ol.View({
         center: [13973849.17, 1000783.15],
         zoom: 13
     })
 });

 $('#layer-select').change(function () {
     var style = $(this).find(':selected').val();
     var i, ii;
     for (i = 0, ii = layers.length; i < ii; ++i) {
         layers[i].setVisible(styles[i] == style);
     }
 });
 $('#layer-select').trigger('change');
```

Is my based map the problem? its SRID or transform value? The error says: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

```
def home(request):
    qry_flood_hazard = FloodHazard.objects.all()
    djf = Django.Django(geodjango='geom', properties=['hazard', 'date_field'])
    geoj = GeoJSON.GeoJSON()
    flood_hazard = geoj.encode(djf.decode(qry_flood_hazard.transform(900913)))

    return  render(request,"index.html",{
            'flood_hazard': flood_hazard,
        })
```

My model `FloodHazard` has this srid, `geom geometry(MultiPolygon,32651)`

Comment: Are you using OpenLayers 2 or OpenLayers 3? The screenshot looks like OpenLayers 2 but the code like OpenLayers 3.

Comment: 3, GeoDjango admin uses Openlayers 2.